# Erlang ETS table events

Tags: erlang, blocking, mnesia, ets

Is there any established mechanism for waiting on an insert into an ETS table if I want to use it for shared state?

I know mnesia support table events, I was thinking a similiar mechanism would be useful for plain ETS so that a process could wait until the data it needed was loaded. I think the only way to do this is to spin loop and continuously request the given key until it arrives, but that seems very inefficient. I would rather get a message callback. If I insert a process between mine and ETS I've just pushed the problem down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest workaround would be to start a `gen_server` process and proxy all insert requests through it. You can then register callbacks by keeping them in the `gen_server` state and call them when the inserted key matches the pattern. It could be even running in a separate application to allow for a dedicated supervisor.

Comment: I wish there was a faster way than this with ETS directly, registering another layer of indirection and serialization is unfortunate. I'm going to mark this answer correct though, since its really the only viable way with ETS.

Comment: This is exactly what Mnesia does, plus lots of other stuff, which is the reason why it's less efficient. Most usages of ETS don't require what you would like to have - notifications per key inserted. As a developer I prefer that ETS is lean and (incredibly) fast and if I need any extra functionality, like the notifications or what not, it's easy to add it.

One more thing is that the overhead should be minimal as you only need to proxy insert requests, read requests can still have a function in your module (for API consistency) but can simply call the corresponding ETS functions.

Answer (score 1):

The ETS doesn't have a concept of events.

However, you can achieve what you've described by putting a reader process into a 'receive' clause, then make a writer process send a message to the reader after data was loaded.

Comment: This just punts the problem down the line though, because the writer process then has to know which of the future other readers care i.e event subscription. For my use case I don't imagine that being very performant. I want to spawn a bunch of workers some of whom may have to wait for other workers to finish processing their segments before they can begin. There isn't an obvious way of mapping out that relationship before hand without serializing the work involved.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from you question that you have lots of workers. In that case you're right, what I've suggested is not the best solution. Looks like your best bet is to write a wrapper around it.

Answer (score 1):

There is not event handling in `ets`. It is pretty low-level language feature and is up to you to make a wrapper around it. BTW, It is way it is done in `mnesia`. So you can wrap your *shared state* into a module and then make subscribe and send yourself.